# EMV Contactless in Verifone ADK using Vx820 Pinpad

Tags: c++, emv, verifone

I already have an application that makes the full flow of EMV and now I want to implement EMV Contactless, this I have done so far:

- Import the library in the compilation: "% VRX_IMPORT% \ lib \ ctls.o"
- Add this line "-l CTLS.LIB = N: /CTLS.LIB"
- Load the libraries "libEMV_CT_Framework.vsl" and "libEMV_CTLS_Client.vsl" in the terminal.

The error occurs in this function:

```
EMV_CTLS_Init_Framework (64, (EMV_CT_CALLBACK_FnT) FrameworkEMVCallbackFunction, (void *) NULL, options, & Result);
```

after calling:

```
EMV_CT_Init_Framework (64, (EMV_CT_CALLBACK_FnT) FrameworkEMVCallbackFunction, (void *) NULL, options);
```

The terminal sometimes stays black and sometimes restarts.

This is the complete EMV Init Function code:

```
unsigned long initializeApplication(unsigned char virtualTerminal, unsigned char EnableTRACE, int autoRetap)
{
  EMV_ADK_INFO        erg;
  unsigned long       virtTerm;
  unsigned long       Result;
  unsigned long       options;

  virtTerm = ((virtualTerminal << 24) & 0xFF000000);

  initializeEmvParameters();

  // Init Framework
  options = virtTerm | EMV_CT_INIT_OPT_CONFIG_MODE | EMV_CT_INIT_OPT_L1_DUMP;
  if (EnableTRACE)
      options |= EMV_CT_INIT_OPT_TRACE | EMV_CT_INIT_OPT_TRACE_CLT;
  erg = EMV_CT_Init_Framework(64, (EMV_CT_CALLBACK_FnT)FrameworkEMVCallbackFunction, (void*)NULL, options);
  if(erg != EMV_ADK_OK)
  {
    APP_TRACE("Init EMV framework returned %d", erg);
    return(EMV_INIT_ERR_INIT_KERNEL);
  }

  options = virtTerm | EMV_CTLS_INIT_OPT_CONFIG_MODE | EMV_CTLS_INIT_OPT_L1_DUMP | autoRetap;
  if (EnableTRACE)
      options |= EMV_CTLS_INIT_OPT_TRACE | EMV_CTLS_INIT_OPT_TRACE_CLT; /*|EMV_CTLS_LED_CALLBACK_EXT*/
  erg = EMV_CTLS_Init_Framework(64, (EMV_CT_CALLBACK_FnT)FrameworkEMVCallbackFunction, (void*)NULL, options, &Result );
  if(erg != EMV_ADK_OK)
  {
    APP_TRACE("Init EMV framework (CTLS) returned %d", erg);
    return(EMV_INIT_ERR_CTLS_ONLY);
  }
}
```

Comment: add more debug lines in your code and enable maximum debugging for the libs you use and see you can find out something.

Comment: What OS version are you running? 
Have you used any of the prebundled solutions to load the appropriate libraries to the terminal? 
Are you trying to use VFI reader version? Do you have CTLS firmware loaded?